# Unexpected sort order on postgres left outer join

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, postgresql-11

**Background**

I'm using Postgres 11 and pgAdmin4 v5.2.  The problem I describe below is on my dev machine which has both the postgres server and pgAdmin client.

Questions I've looked at on SO that deal with incorrect ordering seem related to collation-related issues with ordering of text fields, whereas my problem is on an integer field.

**Setup**

I have a table norm_plans that contains ~5k records.

```
Column   | Type
---------------------------------
canon_id | integer
name     | character varying(200)
...
other fields
```

`canon_id` is autopopulated using a sequence.

I've created a new table `norm_plans_cmp` as a copy of `norm_plans` (`CREATE TABLE norm_plans_cmp AS TABLE norm_plans WITH DATA;`)

I next insert some new records into `norm_plans` and update some existing records (fields other than `canon_id`.

The new records increment the sequence and are assigned `canon_id` values as expected.

I now want to compare `norm_plans` against `norm_plans_cmp` so I perform a left outer join:

```sql
select a.*, b.*
from norm_plans a
left outer join norm_plans_cmp b
on a.canon_id = b.canon_id
order by a.canon_id
```

**Problem**

I would expect records to be sorted by `canon_id`.  This holds true from 1-2000, but after 2,000 I get `canon_id`s from 5,001 to 5,111 (which is the last `canon_id`) and then it again picks up from 2,001.  I'm viewing this data from pgAdmin, see screenshot 1 below showing the shift from 2,000 to 5,001, and screenshot 2 showing the transition again from 5,111 back to 2,001.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Additional observations**

While incorrect, the ordering seems consistent.  Running the query multiple times results in the same (incorrect) ordering.

Despite my question title, I'm not totally sure the left join has anything to do with this.
Running `SELECT * ... ORDER BY canon_id` on `norm_plans` or `norm_plans_cmp` alone also result in incorrect ordering, albeit at different points in the order.

Answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683424/postgres-returns-records-in-wrong-order) suggest index corruption may be a contributing problem, but I have no indexes on either `norm_plans` or `norm_plans_cmp` (`canon_id` is not defined as a PK).

At this point, I'm stumped!

Comment: 1) What happens when you do this in `psql`? 2) In the screenshots the order changes when `b.canon_id` goes from a non-null value to null and then back again. See [order by](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) for how to deal with nulls. 3) Show the ordering(**as text, not image**) for the single table selects.

Comment: you can wrap the query and try to reorder the results
SELECT * FROM (select a.cannon_id as orderid, a.*, b.*
from norm_plans a
left outer join norm_plans_cmp b
on a.canon_id = b.canon_id
order by a.canon_id)  AS sq
ORDER BY sq.orderid

Comment: @AdrianKlaver #1 pointed me in the right direction.  Results in psql are ordered correctly.  And even in pgAdmin, using "Save results to file" results in the correct order.  It would appear that it's just scrolling through the resultset within the pgAdmin data output viewer that is a bit funky.

Comment: Save yourself  headaches and use `psql` as your means of interacting with Postgres. If things fail there then you know you have an issue and not just a program editorializing.

Comment: I do like the convenience of the pgAdmin GUI though :)  But good to know potential weak areas, and falling back to psql as a failsafe is something I'll keep in mind.  @AdrianKlaver if you'd like to frame your helpful comment as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Thanks, it was not really an answer though just some trouble shooting tips. I will leave as comment.